# Python error "list assignment index out of range "

Tags: python

Ubuntu-18.04, Python-2.7.15
I want to initialise a list of 150 zero values as a FIFO stack and then update the stack every second.

```
panel_width = 150  
rx_values = [0] * panel_width  
for i in range(0, panel_width):  
    rx_values[i] = 0  

def refresh():  
    global rx_values  
    # update the stack  
    rx_values.remove(0)  
    rx_values[panel_width -1] = rx_bps  
    # more stuff  
    return  

refresh() # every second
```

produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "./wxpython/bandwidth/bandwidth.1804.2.py", line 64, in rx_refresh  
    rx_values[panel_width -1] = rx_bps  
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You create a list with 150 items. That means the item indexes go from 0 to 149.

Then, you remove the first element of the list:

```
rx_values.remove(0)
```

Therefore, the length of `rx_values` is reduced by 1:

```
> len(rx_values)
148
```

But you try to access the element at index 149:

```
rx_values[panel_width -1] = rx_bps
```

You need to add the new value at the end of your list:

```
rx_values.append(rx_bps)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see all that, but I WANT to change the value at index 149. I am going to chart rx_values, so that current values are at the righthand end (149) and older values are to the left of it, and very old values drop off the lefthand end.

Comment: So what you really want to do is shift the list to the left. I will edit my answer to accord for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused when you remove an element of the list, the list changes sizes. I guess what you want to do is to keep the length of your FIFO queue, if you remove the first element you have to add a new element at the end.

Instead of assigning the last element, you can just append it.

```
panel_width = 150  
rx_values = [0] * panel_width

def refresh():  
    global rx_values  
    # update the stack  
    rx_values.pop(0)  
    rx_values.append(rx_bps)
    # more stuff  
    return  

refresh() # every second
```

I also used a pop instead of a remove, since the pop returns the value you are removing, for a FIFO queue it might be useful to get that value.